# What do the $p$ and $q$ stand for in this quadratic formula?

Tags: quadratics

I study Computer Science in a German university and they use another formula to solve the quadratic equations. They call it the P-Q-Formel.

I'm used to  [this formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEmqo.png) While the Germans use [this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckgQW.png)

Normally I'd find the values of *a, b , c* and *D* and solve the equation using the old formula but I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

What do the *p* and the *q* stand for?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Reduced_quadratic_equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we reduce $ax^2+bx+c=0$ by $a$ we get $$x^2+{b\over a}x+{c\over a}=0$$
Puting $$ p={b\over a}\;\;\;{\rm and} \;\;\;q={c\over a}$$
we get $$x^2+px+q=0$$
So $$ {-p\pm \sqrt{p^2-4q}\over 2} = {-p\over 2}\pm \sqrt{{p^2\over 4}-q}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ after dividing by $$a\ne 0$$ you will get
$$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}=0$$ and now let us define
$$p=\frac{b}{a}$$ and $$q=\frac{c}{a}$$  and you will get
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{p}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q}$$